# scraping data from another website without using modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I'm trying to scraping data from another website using node.js and [wix-code](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-fetch.html)

using this backend code

```
import { fetch } from 'wix-fetch';

export function fetchData() {
let url = 'https://www.brainyquote.com/topics/hacker';

let option = {
    "method": "GET"
}
return fetch(url, option)
.then(result => {
    return result.text();
}).catch(reason => {
    return reason;

 })
}
```

and Client-side code

```
fetchData().then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
})
```

i can get the full response from this [website](https://www.brainyquote.com/topics/hacker)

but what i want is to get the Quotes only and then add them to my database collection without using modules like [Cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution with wix:

```
async function getQuotes(){
  const res = await fetch('https://www.brainyquote.com/topics/hacker');
  const text = await res.text();
  return text.match(/(?<=title="(view quote|view author)">)(.*?)(?=<\/a>)/g)
}
```

**More information:**

Use regex to capture all text between `title="view quote">` (or `title="view quote">` to get authors) and `</a>`

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://www.brainyquote.com/topics/hacker', (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  const data = [];
  res.on('data', (d) => {
    data.push(d);
  });

  res.on('end', ()=>{

        const result = data
        .join("")
        .match(/(?<=title="(view quote|view author)">)(.*?)(?=<\/a>)/g)

        console.log(result);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Will return:

```
[
  'Very smart people are often tricked by hackers, by phishing. I don&#39;t exclude myself from that. It&#39;s about being smarter than a hacker. Not about being smart.',
    'Harper Reed',
    'I&#39;m a hacker, but I&#39;m the good kind of hackers. And I&#39;ve never been a criminal.',
    'Mikko Hypponen',
    'At the end of the day, my goal was to be the best hacker.',
    'Kevin Mitnick',
    'Software Engineering might be science; but that&#39;s not what I do. I&#39;m a hacker, not an engineer.',
    'Jamie Zawinski',
    'If you give a hacker a new toy, the first thing he&#39;ll do is take it apart to figure out how it works.',
    'Jamie Zawinski',
    'Social engineering has become about 75% of an average hacker&#39;s toolkit, and for the most successful hackers, it reaches 90% or more.',
    'John McAfee',
    'I&#39;m a really good hacker, but I&#39;m not a sensible person.',
    'Richard D. James',
    'A hacker is someone who uses a combination of high-tech cybertools and social engineering to gain illicit access to someone else&#39;s data.',
    'John McAfee',
    'The hacker mindset doesn&#39;t actually see what happens on the other side, to the victim.',
    'Kevin Mitnick',
    'I look like a geeky hacker, but I don&#39;t know anything about computers.',
    'Justin Long',
    'The hacker community may be small, but it possesses the skills that are driving the global economies of the future.',
    'Heather Brooke',
    'I&#39;m a bit of a hacker fanatic and know a fair bit about that industry and cyber crime and cyber warfare.',
    'Seth Gordon',
    'It&#39;s true, I had hacked into a lot of companies, and took copies of the source code to analyze it for security bugs. If I could locate security bugs, I could become better at hacking into their systems. It was all towards becoming a better hacker.',
    'Kevin Mitnick',
    'It&#39;s not enough to have a hacker culture anymore. You have to have a design culture, too.',
    'Robert Scoble',
    'If you go to a coffee shop or at the airport, and you&#39;re using open wireless, I would use a VPN service that you could subscribe for 10 bucks a month. Everything is encrypted in an encryption tunnel, so a hacker cannot tamper with your connection.',
    'Kevin Mitnick',
    'I wasn&#39;t a hacker for the money, and it wasn&#39;t to cause damage.',
    'Kevin Mitnick',
    'I&#39;m not an economist; I&#39;m a hacker who has spent his career exploring and repairing large networks.',
    'Dan Kaminsky',
    'In the &#39;80s, society created a caricature of what a hacker or a programmer looked like: a guy wearing a hoodie, drinking energy drinks, sitting in a basement somewhere coding. Today, programmers look like the men we see in the show &#39;Silicon Valley&#39; on HBO. If you look at the message girls are getting, it&#39;s saying, &#39;This is not for you.&#39;',
    'Reshma Saujani',
    'I don&#39;t condone anyone causing damage in my name, or doing anything malicious in support of my plight. There are more productive ways to help me. As a hacker myself, I never intentionally damaged anything.',
    'Kevin Mitnick',
    'I think Linux is a great thing, in the big picture. It&#39;s a great hacker&#39;s tool, and it has a lot of potential to become something more.',
    'Jamie Zawinski',
    'Bitcoin is here to stay. There would be a hacker uproar to anyone who attempted to take credit for the patent of cryptocurrency. And I wouldn&#39;t want to be on the receiving end of hacker fury.',
    'Adam Draper',
    'It was on a bulletin board that I first learned about hacker culture, the &#39;Let&#39;s just break through this wall and see what&#39;s on the other side&#39; mentality.',
    'Harper Reed',
    'Everything about Mark Zuckerberg is pure hacker. Hackers don&#39;t take realities of the world for granted; they seek to break and rebuild what they don&#39;t like. They seek to outsmart the world.',
    'Sarah Lacy',
    'If you&#39;re a juvenile delinquent today, you&#39;re a hacker. You live in your parent&#39;s house; they haven&#39;t seen you for two months. They put food outside your door, and you&#39;re shutting down a government of a foreign country from your computer.',
    'John Waters',
    'The key to social engineering is influencing a person to do something that allows the hacker to gain access to information or your network.',
    'Kevin Mitnick',
    'A smartphone links patients&#39; bodies and doctors&#39; computers, which in turn are connected to the Internet, which in turn is connected to any smartphone anywhere. The new devices could put the management of an individual&#39;s internal organs in the hands of every hacker, online scammer, and digital vandal on Earth.',
    'Charles C. Mann'
]
```

If you wanted to transform the above code into an object and put it in a database you could do something like this:

```js
const data = ['Very smart people are often tricked by hackers, by phishing. I don&#39;t exclude myself from that. It&#39;s about being smarter than a hacker. Not about being smart.','Harper Reed','I&#39;m a hacker, but I&#39;m the good kind of hackers. And I&#39;ve never been a criminal.','Mikko Hypponen','At the end of the day, my goal was to be the best hacker.','Kevin Mitnick','Software Engineering might be science; but that&#39;s not what I do. I&#39;m a hacker, not an engineer.','Jamie Zawinski','If you give a hacker a new toy, the first thing he&#39;ll do is take it apart to figure out how it works.','Jamie Zawinski','Social engineering has become about 75% of an average hacker&#39;s toolkit, and for the most successful hackers, it reaches 90% or more.','John McAfee','I&#39;m a really good hacker, but I&#39;m not a sensible person.','Richard D. James','A hacker is someone who uses a combination of high-tech cybertools and social engineering to gain illicit access to someone else&#39;s data.','John McAfee','The hacker mindset doesn&#39;t actually see what happens on the other side, to the victim.','Kevin Mitnick','I look like a geeky hacker, but I don&#39;t know anything about computers.','Justin Long','The hacker community may be small, but it possesses the skills that are driving the global economies of the future.','Heather Brooke','I&#39;m a bit of a hacker fanatic and know a fair bit about that industry and cyber crime and cyber warfare.','Seth Gordon','It&#39;s true, I had hacked into a lot of companies, and took copies of the source code to analyze it for security bugs. If I could locate security bugs, I could become better at hacking into their systems. It was all towards becoming a better hacker.','Kevin Mitnick','It&#39;s not enough to have a hacker culture anymore. You have to have a design culture, too.','Robert Scoble','If you go to a coffee shop or at the airport, and you&#39;re using open wireless, I would use a VPN service that you could subscribe for 10 bucks a month. Everything is encrypted in an encryption tunnel, so a hacker cannot tamper with your connection.','Kevin Mitnick','I wasn&#39;t a hacker for the money, and it wasn&#39;t to cause damage.','Kevin Mitnick','I&#39;m not an economist; I&#39;m a hacker who has spent his career exploring and repairing large networks.','Dan Kaminsky','In the &#39;80s, society created a caricature of what a hacker or a programmer looked like: a guy wearing a hoodie, drinking energy drinks, sitting in a basement somewhere coding. Today, programmers look like the men we see in the show &#39;Silicon Valley&#39; on HBO. If you look at the message girls are getting, it&#39;s saying, &#39;This is not for you.&#39;','Reshma Saujani','I don&#39;t condone anyone causing damage in my name, or doing anything malicious in support of my plight. There are more productive ways to help me. As a hacker myself, I never intentionally damaged anything.','Kevin Mitnick','I think Linux is a great thing, in the big picture. It&#39;s a great hacker&#39;s tool, and it has a lot of potential to become something more.','Jamie Zawinski','Bitcoin is here to stay. There would be a hacker uproar to anyone who attempted to take credit for the patent of cryptocurrency. And I wouldn&#39;t want to be on the receiving end of hacker fury.','Adam Draper','It was on a bulletin board that I first learned about hacker culture, the &#39;Let&#39;s just break through this wall and see what&#39;s on the other side&#39; mentality.','Harper Reed','Everything about Mark Zuckerberg is pure hacker. Hackers don&#39;t take realities of the world for granted; they seek to break and rebuild what they don&#39;t like. They seek to outsmart the world.','Sarah Lacy','If you&#39;re a juvenile delinquent today, you&#39;re a hacker. You live in your parent&#39;s house; they haven&#39;t seen you for two months. They put food outside your door, and you&#39;re shutting down a government of a foreign country from your computer.','John Waters','The key to social engineering is influencing a person to do something that allows the hacker to gain access to information or your network.','Kevin Mitnick','A smartphone links patients&#39; bodies and doctors&#39; computers, which in turn are connected to the Internet, which in turn is connected to any smartphone anywhere. The new devices could put the management of an individual&#39;s internal organs in the hands of every hacker, online scammer, and digital vandal on Earth.','Charles C. Mann']

const res = [];
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i+=2){
  res.push({quote: data[i], author: data[i+1]});
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hi @kemicofa thank you so much but my problem here is i use [wix-code]( https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-fetch.html ) so i can't use const https = require('https');

Comment: can we chat on twitter or email please ?

Comment: @user7778555 no but you're welcome to join chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188149/geekdpt

Comment: i sent you a message please join the chat if you can, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without cheerio, you would have to parse the HTML contents on your own, which is going to be pain. You are going to have to analyze the HTML response, load the response into a string and then parse out the parts you want using regex or some other method.

Here are a few examples of how you do that with regex:

https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/example_scraping_html.shtml

Answer (score -2):

Scraping is a bad thing since you are basically stealing content that belongs to other authors, so maybe you should consider finding APIs that provide similar content.

But if you really want to scrape - here is a little tutorial for you on scraping.

First of all - what you are doing on backend can be done on the frontend. But actually, we don't need anything to happen on the frontend. Frontend should just receive the Quotes from the backend. Scraping and saving to the database should happen only on the backend.

Cron job fires scraper -> scraper does his job and saves stolen stuff into DB -> server serves content using endpoint

You really need something like `cheerio` or `phantom.js` to do the scraping, don't be afraid of them, they are pretty easy tools.

So the plan:

- Create a scraper using any tool that can easily extract html elements from whole page. This script should connect to your database and save items there.
- Run scraper every N hours/minutes using `node-cron` for example.
- Create endpoint on your server that will serve those Quotes.

Your frontend shouldn't be involved in any kind of scraping or firing scraper. It should just show the data.

Comment: Hi i just did this to learn more not to steal content ( it's a project i did to my self to learn more ) so as i said i wont use any of this modules :)

Comment: scraping is employed by the likes of Google (that's how they index the web) and other companies so I would not say it's "bad" as a general statement. There are cases where it's better to use alternatives to scraping (especially when there exists an API) but sometimes it's the only feasible solution.